# SSIS Runtime on Azure JSON gets invalid JSON file from Azure blob storage

Tags: visual-studio, google-analytics, ssis, azure-blob-storage, kingswaysoft

I am running a local SSIS integration on Visual Studio using the KingswaySoft SSIS Productivity Pack. In my use case, I am trying to fetch data from Google Analytics and put them into an SQL database.

The google analytics connection manager is asking for my credentials in a JSON format. When I am running my integration locally, everything is good as I am using a local JSON file that I have. The problem starts when I try to run my integration on the cloud. I am trying to upload the JSON file on my blob storage and access it with a SAS URL but every time I try to run it I am getting this message:

```
SSIS Productivity Pack (v23.2.0.25101)

KingswaySoft.IntegrationToolkit.ProductivityPack.GoogleServices.GoogleAnalyticsServiceException: An error occurred when attempting to retrieve tokens.Invalid JSON Key file. (SSIS Productivity Pack, v23.2.0.25101 - devenv, v17.7.34031.279)System.Exception 

: Invalid JSON Key file.
```

I tried redownloading the file and running it locally again to see if it's corrupt but it seems to be ok. When I paste the SAS URL in my browser, I can access my JSON file fine but when I parse the URL through a JSON validator I get "Invalid JSON file" (this is not the case with the local version.

- Tested the JSON file locally and works fine but when I upload it in azure blob storage everything breaks. (Read and Write permissions given)
- Uploaded and redownloaded the file to make sure it is not corrupt.
- Tried "Shared file" instead of Blob but got the same thing
- Tried to validate the JSON file's URL with [this tool](https://jsonformatter.curiousconcept.com) but it returns invalid JSON file (the local file validates just fine)
- I suspect something with the encoding as the [tool](https://jsonformatter.curiousconcept.com) I mentioned earlier returns "UTF-8 encoding expected"
- I run a python script that downloads the file and checks its encoding and says that it is in utf-8 format :)

Comment: Thank you for choosing KingswaySoft's Productivity Pack as your integration solution. For this requirement, please reach out to us at www.kingswaysoft.com/about-us/contact-us with more details regarding this issue, and we will be happy to assist you.